# Split string for plus symbols (+)

Tags: java

I would like to split a string `"this is a string i++"` into `[this, is, a, string, i, ++]`.

I tried `string.split("\\s|(?=\\+)")` but it will give me `[this, is, a, string, i, +, +]`.

May I know how I can keep the 2 plus symbols into one?

Comment: This can't be the code you're using, simple split does not allow regex, pleas share the right code you use

Comment: @azro [it does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @azro actually it takes in regex according to [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: whooooops I was thinking in python .. not java, sorry :D I'm reading posts in both language, so switching is hard :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a simple change in regex: `"\\s|(?=\\+)\\b"`

`\\b` : zero-width word boundary

e.g. `"i++".split("\\b")` outputs `[i, ++]`

Try this:

```
String[] arr = "this is a string i++".split("\\s|(?=\\+)\\b");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[this, is, a, string, i, ++]
```